# IPV6 ip address not able to connect from my app when NAT64/DNS64 is connected

Tags: iphone, mac, wifi, internet-sharing, ipv6

SetUp Details :-

IpV4 ethernet cable is connected to MAC machine. Now as per apple documentation steps are followed. Where DNS64/NAT64 is created and hotspot is created.

Device is connected to wi-fi which is created by hotspot on mac machine.

Application status :-

My application is Push to talk (PTT) application. Now i have launched the application where i am establishing to connection to my server.

1) SIP Connection :- FQDN is provided to DNS64/NAT64 which mapped to ipv4 address. so DNS64/NAT64 gave me synthesised ipv6 address. Here TCP connection established successfully.

2) MEDIA Connection :- ipv6 address [Direct server ip] application has given to DNS64/NAT64 but TCP connect is failing as client is sending SYN but "route unreachable error is received".

3) From the browser of device , I am trying to open only ipv6 supported website but it showing "server could not found". But ipv4 and ipv6 both supported website is opening as it's taking ipv4 route.

Problem:-

Please provide a solution how to reach ipv6 address through DNS64/NAT64 network.

Reference :-
Below link i have referred to set up a hotspot  in mac machine.

https://developer.apple.com/support/ipv6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have an IPv4 network then the NAT64 network provided by your Mac will have no connectivity to the real IPv6 internet, only to the synthesized IPv6 addresses that correspond to IPv4. If you need to connect to real IPv6 servers then you need a real IPv6 connection.